# Django: Count Queries and Query time without using connection.queries

Tags: django

For performance monitoring I want to send the count of total queries and the elapsed query time for each request to statsd. In dev/staging I can use connection.queries but I obviously don't want to enable debug on production.

Is there another way to do this without writing a custom cursor wrapper?  Anyone have experience doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Use [django debug toolbar](https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar) specifically designed for debugging purposes. It display various debug information about the current request/response and when clicked, display more details about the panel's content.

Comment: I don't want to have the debug toolbar enabled for every request because it adds latency and has a large memory footprint.  I need something much more lightweight that can be enabled for every request.